# How to Convert the $currentDate (ISODate) to String format while insert/update in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

To capture the Mongo server Date on insert or update we are using $currentDate. The document is inserted with ISODate which is the default.

*ISODate("2021-04-08T12:36:40.209Z")*

Is there any way to convert the $currentDate to String custom date format while inserting/updating? We should see the value as below.

*2021-03-19T08:29:27.245Z*

Comment: Try $convert, although you probably shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sales collection with the following document:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "item" : "abc",
  "price" : 10,
  "quantity" : 2,
  "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z")
}
```

Execution:

```
 db.datetest.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
                              var isoDate = doc.date; 
                              var isoString = isoDate.toISOString(); 
                              db.datetest.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{"date":isoString} }); 
})
```

The document has been updated to this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "item" : "abc",
    "price" : 1,
    "quantity" : 2,
    "date" : "2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z"
}
```